# Communication Theory - Maximum A Posteriori (MAP) Principle

Tags: bayesian

I'm taking a communication theory course and I have some confusion regarding the maximum a posteriori rule.

In my notes it says that,

Consider a communication system where the transmit symbols are x from a choice of J possible symbols. The received symbols are y, from a choice of K possible symbols.
The maximum a posteriori rule says that the receiver makes the following estimate of x,

[image]

It goes on to say that this can be simplified via Baye's Rule as follows,
[image]

That's my confusion. I've tried applying Bayes' Rule, however I seem to have an extra P(yk) on the bottom line. Is it somehow indpendant?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$ \operatorname{argmax}_{x_j} P(x_j, y_k) = \operatorname{argmax}_{x_j} \frac{P(x_j, y_k)}{P(y_k)}$$ as the denominator does not depend on $x_j$.

Comment: Hmm. Why is the denominator independant of x_j? Surely, doesn't the probability that you receive a certain y_k depend on which x_j was sent?

Comment: @AlfroJang80 It's independent, because $x_j$ is not present in this term. It's so to say the prior probability of observing $y_k$ without any knowledge about $x_j$.